# Present Perfect Usage of “Think” for Recent Past

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, british-english, tenses

In such phone conversation context below , instead of "thought" is present perfect form "I've thought it was Frank on the line" acceptable?

**Matt:** Hi John **John:** Hi Frank **Matt:** Oh, this is Matt speaking not Frank. **John:** Sorry Matt. I *thought* it was Frank on the line .You sound very similar.

John's mixing up the voices happens in very recent past(seconds ago) and it has relevance with the present. Why do we generally prefer simple past tense when using the verb "think" in such contexts? In British English present perfect is used commonly for recent past actions and events such as "have told", "has said", "has happened", "have shown" etc. Does it sound natural and acceptable to use present perfect in such phone conversation context? Can you explain please any linguistic differences?

Comment: I think the present perfect implies a recently completed action, as in 'Mary has just arrived'. John's belief that he was speaking to Frank continued until Matt corrected him (not a long time, I know). He could also have said 'I was thinking it was Frank'. but not 'I have thought it was Frank'.

Comment: But he could have said, "I had thought it was Frank"

Comment: 1) doesn't matter if it's in "the very recent past". I **wrote** that first sentence one second ago. 2) probably *everything* that happens in the past "has relevance with the present," so you need to learn about the present perfect from a better source.

Comment: *"Recent past"* is a very bad criterion for deciding whether to use the present perfect.